# How to write a HelloWorld CMake with gRPC

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've followed instructions on the gRPC site's quickstart
https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/

I've also successfully built their HelloWorld example in their build tree, using their cmake files.

Now I want to build my own HelloWorld project outside of their build, using an already built and installed gRPC, to show that I will be able to build an actual project.

I've copy pasted most of their cmake, but I am getting an error:

```
====================[ Build | gRPC_demo | Debug ]===============================
/usr/bin/cmake3 --build /home/cpisz/git-workspace/gRPC_demo/cmake-build-debug --target gRPC_demo -- -j 12
gmake[3]: *** No rule to make target '/protos/helloworld.proto', needed by 'helloworld.pb.cc'.  Stop.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/gRPC_demo.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/gRPC_demo.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:138: gRPC_demo] Error 2
```

My build tree looks like:

```
gRPC_demo
    protos
        helloworld.proto
    main.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
```

The cmake contents look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

project(gRPC_demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

# Threads
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

# Protobuf
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Using protobuf ${protobuf_VERSION}")

set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF protobuf::libprotobuf)
set(_REFLECTION gRPC::grpc++_reflection)
set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protobuf::protoc>)

# gRPC
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Using gRPC ${gRPC_VERSION}")

set(_GRPC_GRPCPP gRPC::grpc++)
set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>)

# Proto file
get_filename_component(hw_proto "/protos/helloworld.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(hw_proto_path "${hw_proto}" PATH)

# Generated sources
set(hw_proto_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.pb.cc")
set(hw_proto_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.pb.h")
set(hw_grpc_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.grpc.pb.cc")
set(hw_grpc_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.grpc.pb.h")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${hw_proto_srcs}" "${hw_proto_hdrs}" "${hw_grpc_srcs}" 
"${hw_grpc_hdrs}"
    COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
    ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    -I "${hw_proto_path}"
    --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
    "${hw_proto}"
    DEPENDS "${hw_proto}")

# Include generated *.pb.h files
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

# Target
add_executable(gRPC_demo
    main.cpp
    ${hw_proto_srcs}
    ${hw_grpc_srcs}
)

target_link_libraries(gRPC_demo
    ${_REFLECTION}
    ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
    ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF}
)
```

I am pretty new to using cmake. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `/protos/helloworld.proto`, which is **absolute** path (because of leading slash) you probably need to use `protos/helloworld.proto`.

Comment: Good stuff. Works now, thanks

Comment: Since protobuf 3.12 you can use its `protobuf_generate` command to invoke protoc and use the `PLUGIN` option for the gRPC plugin. You no longer have to use a custom command.
There is a blog post explaining how to use it: https://www.falkoaxmann.de/dev/2020/11/08/grpc-plugin-cmake-support.html